# How to make every last line the first one for every paragraph on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have many paragraphs of different lengths, with a blank line between each of them, that all end with a different signature (name + date + time). I would like to put those signatures to the top of each paragraph instead of the bottom. In other words, make every last line the first one, for every paragraph.
Your help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please provide some sample input and desired output? This will help clarify your request and get you better answers.

Comment: you will have to write a script. I don't believe that there are any pre-established features in Npp that would suit you, and anything that flexible would essentially be scripting even if npp was the driver. you might be able to pull off some regex wizardry, depending on your strings, but you would likely need additional software. Personally, I'd do it in python, or C# if the box was already set up for appdev.

Comment: There is a python script plugin in notepad++ which can run your python script.

Comment: That may be possible with regular expressions. Please [edit] your question and add some sample text (before and after).

Comment: It's might be possible, but **you have to add a signature format** at least!

Answer (score 0):

*I will adjust RegEx when you update your data/signature format.*

Assuming that your data format is:

```
abcdef(name + date + time)

ghijkl(name + date + time)

mnopqr(name + date + time)

syuvwz(name + date + time)
```

you need to RegEx replace <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd> -> `Replace` tab (`Regular expressions` radio button selected):

```
(.+)(\(name \+ date \+ time\))
```

with:

```
\2\1
```

where:

- `(.+)`, `\1` - is a text before signature.
- `(\(name \+ date \+ time\))`, `\2` - is a signature.